# Conversion from radians to degrees

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I am trying to do a simple trigonometric calculation in C++. The following is an example of the problem I am having with this. As far as I know, C++ works in radians, not degrees. So conversion from radians to degrees should be a simple case of multiplying by 180 and dividing by pi. A simple test is tan(45), which should equate 1. The following program produces a value of 92.8063 however...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double a,b;
    a = tan(45);
    b = a * 180 / 3.14159265;
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're doing it backwards. Don't apply the formula to the *output* of `tan`, apply it to the *parameter*.

Also you'll want to multiply by pi and divide by 180, not vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

The angle is the *input* to `tan`.  So you want:

```
a = 45 * 3.141592653589793 / 180.0;
b = tan(a);
cout << b << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

You must pass radians to the tan function. Also degrees to radian is wrong.

```
 a = tan(45 * 3.14159265 / 180.);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tan *accepts* an angle, and returns a quotient. It is *not* the other way around. You want

```
a = tan(45*3.14159265/180); // Now a is equal to 1.
```